# How to use switch statement to implement collectionView function in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift and trying to implement collectionView function in a ViewController.Now I have three types of UICollectionViewCell,here is my code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    var cell:UICollectionViewCell

    switch collectionView {
        case self.collectionViewCategory:
            cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: categoryIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CategoryCell
            cell.CategoryIcon.image = self.categoryItems[indexPath.item]
        case self.collectionViewHour:
            cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: hourIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! HourCell
            cell.hourItem.text = self.hourItems[indexPath.item]
        default:
            //do nothing.
    }
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    return cell
}
```

I want to declare a variable cell using AnyObject,but I got a lot of mistakes.After changing to UICollectionViewCell,the errors vanish,then still not work.

Comment: switch indexPath.section or indexPath.row

Comment: Do not post duplicates of your own question

Comment: What do you mean by still not work? Did you got an error or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You may using a switch like this:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            <#code#>
        case 1:
            <#code#>
        default:
            <#code#>
        }
    }
```

or you may use the indexPath.section